# Multiple SSL config on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I'm trying to get multiple SSL certs configured on Tomcat 8.5 with a single IP. My relevant server.xml looks like this:

```
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="9443" />
<Connector port="9443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" hostName="firstnationalsculpturepark.com"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" defaultSSLHostConfigName="firstnationalsculpturepark.com"
>
    <SSLHostConfig hostname="firstnationalsculpturepark.com">
        <Certificate
                certificateKeystoreFile="/apache/conf/twinfeats.keystore"
               certificateKeystorePassword="xxxxxxx"
               certificateKeyAlias="firstnationalsculpturepark"
        />
     </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

On startup, the following is logged:

```
03-Aug-2016 16:47:04.541 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'hostName' to 'firstnationalsculpturepark.com' did not find a matching property.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as the hostName property is indicated in the Tomcat 8.5 docs as an attribute for SSLHostConfig. (The above error then causes an error trying to find the default keystore file since it isn't using the one I've specified, but that is expected.)

Comment: `hostName` is a property for `SSHConfig` but not for `Connector`, and you are getting the error on `Connector`

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! I removed the hostName attribute from Connector, and now the only error that remains is it complaining that it can't find .keystore, even though I'm trying to configure twinfeats.keystore. Any ideas?

Comment: I made some changes and the error is gone, but I don't understand why. :) I added the deprecated keystoreFile and keystorePass attributes to the Connector, and now it starts ok. So it would seem is doesn't like my defaultSSLHostConfigName?

Comment: I could not get this working still, but wanted to add a comment that the sslProtocol attribute is also not supported any more unless you are using JSSE.  A list of supported attributes are located here: [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html).

Answer (score 4):

I got multiple SSLConfig to work, but note the "hostname" on the SSLHostConfig above should have a capital 'N' eg hostName. 
PLUS... I had to upgrade to tomcat 8.5.13 (latest) as it didn't seem to work with 8.5.4 I was using at the time.

My example for for others:

```
<Connector port="443"
           ............
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"                              
           defaultSSLHostConfigName="mydomain.com">
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="mydomain.com" 
                   certificateVerification="false">
        <Certificate
            certificateKeystoreFile="my.ks"
            certificateKeystorePassword="password"
            certificateKeyAlias="cert1"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="mydomain2.com" 
                   certificateVerification="false">
        <Certificate
            certificateKeystoreFile="my.ks"
            certificateKeystorePassword="password"
            certificateKeyAlias="cert2"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
 </Connector>
```